# docker-compose execute command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

I'm trying to put some commands in my `docker-compose` file to be ran in my container and they don't work.

I map a volume from host to container where I have a Root certificate, all I want to do is to run this command `update-ca-certificates`, so it will  updates the directory /etc/ssl/certs with my cert in the container, however it is not happening.

I tried to solve this in a Dockerfile and I can see that the command runs, but it seems that the cert is not present there and just appears after I login to the container.

What I end doing is to get into the container, then I run the needed commands  manually.

This is the piece of my `docker-compose` file that I have been trying to use:

```
build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: >
      sh -c "ls -la /usr/local/share/ca-certificates &&
             update-ca-certificates"
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    volumes:
      - "c:/certs_for_docker:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates"
```

In the same way I cannot run `apt update` or anything like this, but after connecting to the container with `docker exec -it test_alerting_comp /bin/bash` I can pull anything from any repo.

My goal is to execute any needed command on building time, so when I login to the container I have already the packages I will use and the Root cert updated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post you Dockerfile ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA I was just missing the `env vars` in the Dockerfile, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you do package update/install and copy certificates in the Dockerfile?

**Dockerfile**

```
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install whatever

COPY ./local/certificates /usr/local/share/my-certificates

RUN your-command-for-certificates
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  your-service:
    build: ./dir
```

Comment: Hi, Your answer help me to understand what I did wrong... The thing is that I thought  that using the environment variables only in the `docker-compose` file was enough to have the container ready to use the linux repo, and it is not like that.

What I did was to use a `Dockerfile` with the enviroment variables, then I put the needed Linux commands as you advised and Voila!! evertything is working. Thank you :-)